# Will presentViewController cause memory to run out?

Tags: ios, swift

There is something I misunderstand. I am currently working on an app using Swift. To simplify multiple developers working on it, the project is split into multiple storyboards. When the app starts up, we use the App Delegate to determine whether or not to present a tutorial.

Whichever view is chosen, we instantiate the storyboard and then the initial view controller like so:

```
// Show the Welcome Tutorial
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

let initialStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "WelcomeTutorial", bundle: nil)

let initialViewController: TutorialVC = initialStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TutorialVC") as! TutorialVC

self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController

self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Then, when we want to move to a different storyboard, we use the same code, but replace the last two lines with presentViewController. However, it is my understanding that this is building a stack. We are never going to call dismissViewController or return to the previous view controller, so it can be dismissed. Is there a better way to do this without creating a stack? I am worried the stack is wasting memory. I can possibly get segues to work with storyboard references, but I don't know if this creates the same problem.

Comment: When you say you "use the same code", are you re-creating the window, or are you simply presenting the main view controller *over* the tutorial? If the latter, why not simply pop the current (tutorial) and then present the main?

Comment: We get the other storyboard (line 2) and then a view controller from that storyboard (line 3). Then we use presentViewController to present the new one. Now that you say that I feel pretty dumb. If I do not want to build a stack of controllers, I can call dismissViewController then immediately call presentView to show the new one? I had always thought this would briefly show a blank screen while the new one presented.

Comment: It might display a white screen - you'll probably want to test it and see what happens. Or present an empty/single-view controller *first* containing a background color or image and always keep that at the bottom of your stack, swapping the tutorial/main controller *on top* of that.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. When presenting view controllers like you described, you are building a stack. If you don't need a modal view controller anymore, dismiss it. If window's root controller needs to be swapped out for a different one, assign a new one and let the old one die. As always, watch out for strong references!